# How should you internationalize javascript spread in multiple files but build in one?

Tags: block-editor, localization

I have followed the instructions for internationalization on: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/internationalization/, but it doesn't seem to play well with the development tools for Gutenberg. It will find all the translations in the `src` directory in the multiple `js` files and will use that as the relative paths while the `npm run build` will make one `build/index.js` file which I am enqueueing. The `wp i18n make-json languages --no-purge` will create multiple files which the MD5 won't work (probably because of the relative paths) and I can't name them al `${domain}-${local}-${handler}.json`.

---

To have a better understanding what I mean. I now have the following:

```
npm init
npm i --save-dev --save-exact @wordpress/scripts
mkdir build
mkdir src
cd src 
touch index.js
touch edit.js
```

**index.js**

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';

import edit from './edit.js';

registerBlockType( 'gbg/myguten', {
    title: __( "My Gutenberg Example", "gbg" ),
    category: "widgets",
    edit
} );
```

**edit.js**

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

export default () => (<h1>{ __( "Hello World", "gbg" ) }</h1>);
```

I then generate the translations:

```
mkdir lang
wp i18n make-pot ./ lang/myguten.pot
cp myguten.pot myguten-en_US.po
wp i18n make-json myguten-en_US.po --no-purge
```

This will generate multiple json files, while I rather have one combined json file. `npm run build` will generate one index.js file which I use to register in WordPress.

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Guten
 * Text Domain: gbg
 */
function gbg_myguten_block_init() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'gbg', false, dirname( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '/lang/' );

    wp_register_script(
        'gbg-myguten-script',
        plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-i18n' ),
        time(),
        true
    );

    register_block_type( 
        'gbg/myguten', 
        array(
            'editor_script' => 'gbg-myguten-script',
        ) 
    );

    wp_set_script_translations( 'gbg-myguten-script', 'gbg', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'lang' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'gbg_myguten_block_init' );
```

Now it will search for `${domain}-${locale}-${handle}.json` while multiple json files exist.

Comment: `${domain}-${locale}-${handle}.json` is indeed loaded before the individual JSON/translation files, but there's a good reason why `make-json` generates those files as explained [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/09/new-javascript-i18n-support-in-wordpress/). Nevertheless, you can try [po2json](https://github.com/mikeedwards/po2json). :)

Comment: I understand po2json is replaced with wp i18n make-json languages --no-purge. Still don't understand what to do with the multiple json files for relative paths like src/index.js and src/edit.js while the build is build/index.js with all code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(I revised this answer mainly to let other readers and you know the issues I originally noticed in your steps as shown in the question.)*

So in my original answer, I was focused on suggesting you to just go with the multiple script translation files, but I thought I should clarify the three things below:

> It will find all the translations in the `src` directory in the multiple `js` files and will use that as the relative paths while the `npm run build` will make one `build/index.js` file which I am enqueueing.

- Yes, [`wp i18n make-json`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/i18n/make-json/) will create one [JED](https://messageformat.github.io/Jed/)-formatted JSON file *per JavaScript source file* — [more details on Make WordPress](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/09/new-javascript-i18n-support-in-wordpress/).
- As with the `npm run build` (which uses the [`wp-scripts` package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-scripts/)), it — as far as I know — only builds JavaScript source files (`.js`) and not JED files which are JSON files. (There is a JS linter and other tools, though.)

> The `wp i18n make-json` will create multiple files which the MD5 won't work (probably because of the relative paths)

- The files would work so long as you give the proper file name to your PO files where the format is `${domain}-${locale}.po` (see [Plugin Handbook » Loading Text Domain](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/#loading-text-domain)) — e.g. `my-plugin-it_IT.po` if the *text domain* is `my-plugin` and the *locale* is set to `it_IT` (Italiano).

  But then, you used the wrong text domain, e.g. with the command `wp i18n make-pot ./ lang/myguten.pot`, you should've used `gbg` and not `myguten` because the `Text Domain` in your plugin header is `gbg` (i.e. `Text Domain: gbg`).

  Additionally, your `cp` ("copy") command should have been preceded by `cd lang`.
- As with the MD5 thing, it is the MD5 hash of the JS source file path as you can see in the PO file — so the path is (or *should be*) relative to the plugin folder.

  E.g. Structure of my sample plugin:

  ```
  wpse-366881/
    build/
      index.js <- relative path = build/index.js
    lang/
    src/
      edit.js  <- relative path = src/edit.js
      index.js <- relative path = src/index.js
    index.php
    package.json
  ```

> I rather have one combined JSON file.

- In that case, you can use [`po2json`](https://github.com/mikeedwards/po2json) and [`npx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) to run the executable `po2json` file.

### So how should you internationalize JavaScript spread in multiple files but *build in one*?

Just follow the steps in the question, except:

1. Make sure the translation files (POT, PO, MO and JED/JSON) — i.e. the code inside and the file names — are using the text domain as defined in the *plugin header*. Additionally, put all the translation files in the correct directory.

   E.g. `wp i18n make-pot ./ lang/gbg.pot`
2. There's no need to run the `wp i18n make-json` command which creates the multiple files, and just use `po2json` to create a single JED/JSON file from a PO file.

   And the command for that is: (Note that as of writing, WordPress uses JED 1.x)

   `npx po2json <path to PO file> <path to JSON file> -f jed1.x`

   E.g. `npx po2json lang/gbg-en_US.po lang/gbg-en_US-gbg-myguten-script.json -f jed1.x`

### Sample Plugin I used for testing purposes (and for other readers to try)

You can find it [on GitHub](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-366881) — *tried & tested working on WordPress 5.4.1, with the site locale/language set to `it_IT`/Italiano.* And the code are basically all based on your code, except in `index.php`, I used the `build/index.asset.php` file to [automatically load dependencies and version](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/js-build-setup/#dependency-management).

And btw, the plugin was initially based on [the example here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/tree/master/01-basic-esnext).

Comment: Thanks to your sample project I was able to find the most important key to the problem. `make-pot` makes us of the `/* Plugin Name: Descriptor */` or `/* Theme Name: Descriptor */` to work out how to generate the`.pot` file so that it finds the translations and also targets both build/index.js and src/index.js. However if you don't have that description somewhere in a file directly in your source directory. It won't work.

Comment: When we investigate `MakePotCommand.php` this is confirmed by the method `get_main_file_data`. It runs through the files in the source directory. It will search the `style.css`-file for the Theme header or any `.php` file for a valid Plugin header. If none of these can be found it will treat it as a regular project. I haven't investigated what that actually means, however it can't find any string translations.

Comment: `make-pot` is just one way we can use to internationalize a WordPress plugin or theme - one can also [manually create the POT file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fxbenard/Blank-WordPress-Pot/master/Blank-WordPress.pot) and use tools like Poedit to generate the PO/MO translation files. And yes, the `Plugin/Theme Name` header has always been a requirement when creating a plugin / theme.

Answer (score 1):

> With the help I got from the marked answer written by Sally CJ I was
>   able to write this answer which is a more compact version of what I
>   was looking for as an answer.

---

> I am using the dutch locale (nl_NL) in the samples below,
>   but feel free to use any other locale instead like it_IT or en_US.

---

> The `make-pot` WP CLI command only does the expected job when used in
>   the root directory of your theme or plugin. This is also where the
>   file lives that contains the [Plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/) or [Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) header.

---

To get the expected result run the following commands:

```
1. wp i18n make-pot .
2. cp ./languages/my-plugin-slug.pot ./languages/my-plugin-slug-nl_NL.po
3. npx po2json languages/my-plugin-slug-nl_NL.po languages/my-plugin-slug-nl_NL-my-plugin-script-handler.json -f jed1.x;
```

In your plugin PHP-file use the following code:

```
function register_block_my_gutenberg_block() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'my-plugin-slug', false, plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' ); 

    $asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php' );

    wp_register_script(
        'my-plugin-script-handler',
        plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.js',
        $asset_file['dependencies'],
        $asset_file['version'],
        true
    );

    register_block_type(
        'my-namespace/my-gutenberg-block',
        array(
            'editor_script' => 'my-plugin-script-handler'
        )
    );

    wp_set_script_translations( 
        'my-plugin-script-handler', 
        'my-plugin-slug',
        plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' 
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_block_my_gutenberg_block' );
```

As written in the documentation, [How to Internationalize Your Plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/), "The text domain must match the slug of the plugin". That's why `my-plugin-slug` is used in the places marked for text-domain.

**PoEdit**

You can also use PoEdit for translation. Just use the `make-pot` as described above in step 1 and then open the newly create pot file in PoEdit. Create the translation and save it as `my-plugin-slug-nl_NL.po`. Then use the command in step 3 to generate the `.json`-file.

**Package.json**

You can make life a little bit easier by adding `make-pot` and `make-json` to your `package.json` file. Now if you `npm run make-pot`, the pot file is created. Use it to translate. Then use `npm run make-json` to create the json files for all the `.po` files. Make sure you change the `my-plugin-handler.json` to the name of your script handler defined in your PHP file with `wp_register_script`.

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "format:js": "wp-scripts format-js",
    "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js src",
    "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "make-pot": "wp i18n make-pot .",
    "make-json": "find . -iname \"*.po\" -type f -exec sh -c 'npx po2json $0 $(dirname $0)/$(basename $0 .po)-my-plugin-script-handler.json -f jed1.x' {} \\;"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers here suggest the use of `npx po2json` instead of `wp i18n make-json` but that might not be ideal for everyone because `wp i18n make-json` is the standard way of generating json files. Here's how you make it work:

- Make sure you use the @wordpress/scripts to build your JS. This package uses webpack behind the scenes and all the translation functions are already preserved so the make-pot scanner can scan them. More about this package: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#advanced-usage

[image]

- When running the make-pot command, explicitly include the JS build directory and exclude the JS source directory: `wp i18n make-pot ./ languages/domain.pot --exclude=path/to/js/src --include=path/to/js/build/ --ignore-domain`. Now your POT file will only reference the generated files that are actually enqueued on the page.
- Run make-json. The md5 hashes of the generated JSON files will correctly reference the actual scripts loaded on the page.

Comment: The other answers do mention make-josn though, but po2json if you only want one output file. When you say it won't work for everyone what's wrong with it?

Comment: Edited for clarity. I meant it might not be ideal for everyone.