# How to translate multiple blocks within one plugin

Tags: block-editor, translation

I'm struggling to get translations working on my custom blocks.

I have a plugin with multiple blocks, following this file structure:

```
/languages
/build
  ..build files
/src
  /block-one
    block.json
    edit.js
    index.js
    save.js
    style.scss
  /block-two
    block.json
    ...
index.php
```

Inside my index.php file I have a single init function:

```
function textdomain_register_blocks() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/block-one' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/block-two' );
    ...
}
add_action( 'init', 'textdomain_register_blocks' );
```

I've been trying to get translations working for my blocks, following the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/internationalization/) and these questions:

- [Using wp_set_script_translations without manually registering the script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/407346/using-wp-set-script-translations-without-manually-registering-the-script)
- [How should you internationalize javascript spread in multiple files but build in one?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/366881/how-should-you-internationalize-javascript-spread-in-multiple-files-but-build-in)

I have the .pot, .po and .json files created, apparently successfully, but can't seem to get the translations to apply.

I thought that the correct approach would be to add this to my `textdomain_register_blocks` function above

```
function textdomain_register_blocks() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/block-one' );
    register_block_type( __DIR__ . '/build/block-two' );
    ...
    
    $script_handle = generate_block_asset_handle( 'textdomain/block-one', 'editorScript' );
    wp_set_script_translations( $script_handle, 'textdomain', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'languages' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'textdomain_register_blocks' );
```

Then in my `plugin/languages` folder I have the .json files generated by `wp i18n make-json`, in the format `<textdomain>-<locale>-<md5>.json`

E.g.

```
textdomain-fr_FR-5f07d4aaf1c458031fefa9b4be7322e5.json
```

I've also tried renaming the translation files to the format `<textdomain>-<locale>-<script handle>.json`, which gives us:

```
textdomain-fr_FR-textdomain-block-one-editor-script.json
```

However, this doesn't appear to work.

I have also tried moving the generated .json files directly to `wp-content/languages/plugins`, following the naming convention `<textdomain>-<locale>-<md5>.json`, but this doesn't work either.

I'm clearly missing something, so any help is much appreciated!

**Edit**: In case it's relevant, I have my plugin in the `mu-plugins` directory

Answer (score 0):

**/edit**
The question is very similar to [Using wp_set_script_translations without manually registering the script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/407346/197528) and incidentally, my reply is very similar to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/407513/197528

--

**First**, you indeed need to call `wp_set_script_translations()` so that your assets (eg from `wp_enqueue_script`) get a chance to be associated with a translation's path actually pointing to /languages.
By default, the call to `wp_set_script_translations` made by `register_block_type` is passed a empty `$path` value.

**Second**, in order to set the the translation, you indeed need the right script *handle* for this to work. You could compute them the way `register_block_type` does by the mean of `register_block_script_handle` (like you did), or retrieve the handles from `register_block_type` itself.

Example:

```php
    public const DOMAIN = 'foobar';
    private $handles = [];

    // add_action('init')
    public function init_blocks($blocks, $current_path)
    {
        foreach ($blocks as $path) {
            $s = register_block_type($path);
            if ($s) {
                array_push($this->handles, ...$s->view_script_handles, ...$s->editor_script_handles);
            }
        }
    }

    // add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts')
    // But don't forget wp admin script
    public function enqueue_assets()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain(self::DOMAIN, false, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/languages');
        foreach ($this->handles as $handle) {
            wp_set_script_translations($handle, self::DOMAIN, plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'languages');
        }
    }
```

**Third**: Translation applies the block is inserted within the Gutenberg editor (based on profile's language). If anything changed afterward (adding `wp_set_script_translations` or changing translation), the block must be **removed** and **re-added** because once saved, the markup is static (strings are fixed and will not change according to visitor's language)

I believe your error may be related to this last point (having added `wp_set_script_translations` later but not seeing the translation in your existing Gutenberg window because the blocks need to be removed and re-added)

A last though thing: i18n JSON file suffixes are based on the md5 of the **build** file name of your block, eg `build/block-one/script.js` or `build/block-two/block.js` and this path must exactly appear as-is in the PO's string source.

Since this won't happen because PO files are generated from source and not build files you need this map-file between sources and build files to be passed to `wp i18n make-json languages --use-map`.